# C# Double Quote Issues

Tags: c#

Below is my source data.

```
string s = "text"some text in quotes next text.";
```

when i try to assign, it's throwing an error.

when i use this `\` escape character before ", it is working fine.

```
string s = "text\"some text in quotes\" next text.";
```

but my client will send data like below only

text"some text in quotes next text.

how can I assign the above value to string?

I have tried using like below, but throwing error.

```
string a1 = @"text"some text in quotes next text.";
```

Comment: Define "my client will send data".  What does that mean?  If you're receiving this value in the form of a variable then where does a literal string even come into the picture here?

Comment: _"my client will send data"_ Then you don't have the problem, have you? If this is just for testing, test it  under real conditions and use a file (or whatever it is).

Comment: This makes no real sense. You already know how to escape quotes. What is the problem?

Comment: What is the incoming data? Escaping of specific characters in your code has nothing to do with the same characters inputted through console, textbox, read from XML, whatever - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma. They will be in the string as they are being inputted - no escaping and replacing will be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your double quotes:

```
 string s = "text\"some text in quotes next text.";
```

Alternative:

```
 string s = @"text""some text in quotes next text.";
```

So if you receive the string, or parse it from xml, look up the double quotes and escape them as described above before assigning it to a string variable, like:

```
 string s = xmlValue.Replace('"', '\"');
```

Comment: My incoming data is text"some text in quotes next text.First of all how can i assign that value to string?

Comment: @user2979719 How is your data coming in? Is your client typing a literal string into your code, is it a POST parameter, is it data coming over a socket, is your function being called by other code...?

Comment: text"some text in quotes next text. my data is coming from the xml, I need to read that data to string..

Comment: By processing the string before assignment and making sure the double quotes are escaped.

Comment: like text" "data"" ??

Comment: How can i  processing the string before assignment and making sure the double quotes are escaped?